# How to customize focus navigation in a ViewGroup

Tags: android

I have a View Group and it has 2 focusable Views as its children.
I would like know how I can customize how focus is being passed
between these 2 Views. In other words, when I press the Down Key or
the Up Key in the emulator, i want to control which of these children
has focus.

I read the JavaDoc of ViewGroup, I see these 2 methods.

```
public View focusSearch (View focused, int direction)
public boolean requestFocus (int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect)
```

But I am confused which of these method I should over-ride to achieve
what I want.

Thank you for any advice.

Regards,

Comment: Have you managed it somehow? se I have a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538526/custom-viewgroup-focus-handling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also try using `android:nextFocusDown` attribute, like in focus_3.xml example from the `ApiDemos`.