# Custom ViewGroup focus handling

Tags: android, focus, android-view, android-custom-view, viewgroup

Let's say I have a custom ViewGroup which is focusable and has some child views which are focusable as well (A custom vertical menu for Android set-top-boxes which should react on remote controller).

I need to pass a focus to some of the child views whenever the custom ViewGroup gains the focus.

I set `descendantFocusability` to `beforeDescendants` and set `OnFocusChangeListener` to the custom ViewGroup but `OnFocusChangeListener.onFocusChanged()`is never called. It looks like `beforeDescendants` does not work as I expected. Actually setting the `beforeDescendants` works the same as setting the `afterDescendants` - The focus is taken by the nearest child view and the custom ViewGroup does not have an opportunity to decide which child view should take the focus.

How can I achieve the desired behavior? What are the best practices to handling focuses in `ViewGroup`s?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?  I'm looking for a solution to a similar problem.  I want to know when the ViewGroup "loses" focus, i.e. no child view has focus.

Comment: @AlanKley Sorry for late response...unfortunatelly I did not find any solution for this. I "solved" this by setting OnFocusChangeListener to all of ViewGroup's children and have the logic (of which child should get focus) inside the listener... If you find any solution, feel free to write it here :)

Answer (score 9):

After digging in Android sources I understand how to dispatch focus to `ViewGroup`'s children. For example I have custom `ViewGroup` with few `EditText` fields inside. When the user clicks on `ViewGroup` (outside of each `EditText`) I want to dispatch focus to one of fields.

To do this we need to set descendantFocusability to `FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS`. It means that we can handle focus event **before** our custom view will try to focus itself:

```
setDescendantFocusability(FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
```

Next step is to override `onRequestFocusInDescendants` method, it will be invoked **before** custom view's `requestFocus` if flag `FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS` was set. In this method we can request child focus:

```
@Override
protected boolean onRequestFocusInDescendants(final int dir, final Rect rect) {
    return getChildAt(this.target).requestFocus();
}
```

One important thing with this method: if we return `true` here, our custom view will not be requested to focus (only with `FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS`).

In such a manner we can change `target` field to change which child will be focused when `ViewGroup` is clicked.

---

For better understanding you can find `requestFocus` method in `ViewGroup` in Android sources.

Answer (score 5):

I have the similar problem. In our android TV application we wanna select the last focused position of our custom menu (it is custom vertical LinearLayout).

Your should override method `addFocusables(views: ArrayList<View>, direction: Int, focusableMode: Int)` . This method is called when ViewRootImpl searches all available focusable views. Flags FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS and FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS are only determine position of insertion parent view into focusable views. In case of FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS your custom view will be added **before your child**. In case of FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS your custom view will be added **after your child**.

The logic of overriding is to add only your custom view in the list, when your didn't have focused child before.

```
override fun addFocusables(views: ArrayList<View>, direction: Int, focusableMode: Int) {
    // if we did have focused child before, we must add only parent view
    // otherwise our child already has focus, and we don't wont to change focus behavior
    if (focusedChild == null) {
        views.add(this)
    } else {
        super.addFocusables(views, direction, focusableMode)
    }
}
```

You also must override `requestFocus(direction: Int, previouslyFocusedRect: Rect)` because you mast pass focus into you child or decide that your cannot do it.

```
override fun requestFocus(direction: Int, previouslyFocusedRect: Rect): Boolean = 
        getViewToFocus()?.requestFocus() ?: false
```

In this example getViewToFocus() returns the child which I want to be focused or null if we don't have any child

```
private fun getViewToFocus() =
        when {
            lastSelectedPos in 0..childCount -> getChildAt(lastSelectedPos)
            isNotEmpty() -> getChildAt(0)
            else -> null
        }
```

I use Kotlin in examples, but your can use java as well. Enjoy!

Comment: For focus on Android TV, I recommend https://www.jianshu.com/p/bc7b3878f140